# Invalid conversion from int* to int even though I delimit the pointer

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I've received the following error:

```
NQueens.cpp:35:19: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
    solution[i].y = *(possibilities + i);
```

I believe I delimited the pointer so that I can apply the value being pointed to the y coordinate for the n-queens problem. Am I missing anything, or is my compiler being dumb?

My header file:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef QUEEN
#define QUEEN

struct Queen {
    int x, y;
};
#endif // !QUEEN
```

My C++ code:

```
#include "Queen.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool isDiag(int, int, int, int);
bool solutionFinder(int, int, vector<int*>);

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter a number n for the n-queen problem:\n";
    cin >> n;
    vector<int*> possibilities;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int arrayInt[n];
        arrayInt[0] = i + 1;
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            arrayInt[j] = 0;
        }
        possibilities.push_back(arrayInt);
    }
    if (!solutionFinder(1, n, possibilities))
    {
        cout << "No Solution.\n";
    }

    Queen solution[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        solution[i].x = i + 1;
        solution[i].y = *(possibilities.begin() + i);
    }
    cout << "Solution: [(" << solution[0].x << "," << solution[0].y << ")";
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        cout << ", (" << solution[i].x << "," << solution[i].y << ")";
    cout << "]\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:
I've tried the fix that mch suggested and now it compiles fine. However, I've ran into a new problem. When trying to print the coordinates for the queens, I'm getting what I believe are the locations of the values in memory.
Example:

```
Enter a number n for the n-queen problem:
4
Solution: [(1,1163548928), (2,32764), (3,1163548704), (4,32764)]
```

Comment: You cannot apply pointer arithmetics on a `std::vector<T>`, use the `std::vector<T>::iterator` there instead to do that (`*(possibliities.begin() + 1)`).

Comment: I'm not trying to get to a different part of the vector, I'm trying to iterate the pointer at possibilities.begin() by 1 to access the next part of the array that happens to be there.

Comment: then you want `possibilities[1][i]`, but then you are dereferencing an array, which went out of scope some line above.

Comment: What pointer are you talking about? One of those stored in `vector<int*> possibilities;`? Which one of these do you want / need to access?

Comment: So, all of the pointers in vector<int*> possibilities are pointers to arrays. I'm trying to pull data out of the array that its pointer is located at possibilities.begin().

Comment: `*(possibilities.begin() + i)` is a poor way of writing `possibilities[i]`. The vector elements are pointers so you're trying to assign a pointer to an `int`. The error message is correct.

Comment: Why not use a vector of vectors?

Comment: To quote my assignment: " It should use an 1xN array to record the positions of the queens in columns 1, 2, ..., n, respectively."

Comment: About your last edit. Each variable length array `int arrayInt[n];` *created inside the `for` loop* is destroyed at the end of the loop. The vector `possibilities` holds dangling pointers and you are off into undefined behavior. All your code could **simpler** and **correct** if you make `possibilities` a `vector<vector<int>>` and forget about this pointer stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with this code, but your immediate problem stems from this:

```cpp
vector<int*> possibilities;
...
for (...)
{
    int arrayInt[n];
    ...
    possibilities.push_back(arrayInt);
}
...
solution[i].y = *(possibilities.begin() + i);
```

You have a vector of `int*` pointers, which are pointing at `int[]` arrays which you are creating inside a loop (and will be destroyed at the end of each loop iteration, thus leaving the vector holding *dangling pointers* to invalid memory).

You are then iterating through the `vector`, extracting each `int*` pointer and trying to assign it as-is to a single `int`, thus the compiler error.  You would need to instead dereference the `int*` to get individual `int` values from the array, eg:

```cpp
int *arr = *(possibilities.begin() + i);
solution[i].y = arr[someIndex];
```

Based on what you have shown, I think you have implemented your `solutionFinder()` incorrectly (but you didn't show how you actually implemented it).  Rather than outputting a `vector` of `int[]` arrays, it would be better to have it output a vector of `Queen`s instead, eg:

```cpp
#include "Queen.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool isDiag(int, int, int, int);
bool solutionFinder(int, int, vector<Queen>&);

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter a number n for the n-queen problem:\n";
    cin >> n;

    vector<Queen> solution;
    solution.reserve(n);

    if (!solutionFinder(1, n, solution))
    {
        cout << "No Solution.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Solution: [(" << solution[0].x << "," << solution[0].y << ")";
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        cout << ", (" << solution[i].x << "," << solution[i].y << ")";
    cout << "]\n";
    
    return 0;
}

bool isDiag(int, int, int, int)
{
    // ...
}

bool solutionFinder(int, int, vector<Queen> &solution)
{
    // populate solution with Queen's as needed...
    for (...)
    {
        Queen q;
        q.x = ...;
        q.y = ...;
        solution.push_back(q);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Contrary to the various comments you /can/ do can do arithmetic on "random access" iterators.

The issue is that you declared you have a vector of pointers.

You access the iterator like a pointer using `operator *` to indirect, but then you would would need to indirect again (another *) to follow the pointer held in the cell of the vector.

It is simper to use the array index syntax with vector `poss[i]` rather than `*(poss.begin()+i)` but you still need to do that extra indirection if you do indeed have a vector of pointers, `*(poss[i])` which looks a bit ugly.

Comment: I tried that and I'm getting `invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)`.